# Using list of sample names in file to copy from directory

Tags: python, bash

I have a list of sample names in a file separated by line eg:

```
sample1
sample2 
sample3
```

I need to somehow copy the files from another directory on the machine to my directory for this list of files.
eg `cp /path/to/file/sample1.fasta /path/to/my_directory` for every line in the file of sample names (the path and file type are always the same such that for sample two it would be `cp /path/to/file/sample2.fasta /path/to/my/directory`)

Can anyone help?  I have thousands of samples so am desperate to find a coding solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I support janos's answer
But since you tagged the question with python aswell
I wanted to supply a solution.

#### Parsing

```
samples = open("/path/to/sample/file", "r").readlines()
```

This will give you a list of names for the samples.

#### Copying

In order to copy files you could use `shutil`:

```
import shutil
trailer = ".fasta"
for sampleName in samples:
    shutil.copy2("/path/to/file/sampleName" + trailer, "/path/to/destination/")
```

From the `shutil` documentation:

> shutil module offers a number of high-level operations on files and collections of files.

Using shutil.copy2 you can copy the file including it's metadata
Such as permissions, last modification time, etc.
*Note* that file owner and group can not get copied.

If you do not want to use external libraries and code
You could simply use read/write I/O functions and write from source to dest

Comment: nearly works except that it prints sampleName rather than the line from the file samples, presumably sampleName needs to be outside of the quotation marks??

Comment: sorry figured it out - thanks very much for the python solution - adapted it to something which works very nicely for my needs

Answer (score 1):

Use the `read` command in a `while` loop:

```
targetdir=/path/to/my/directory

while read -r file; do
    cp "$file" "$targetdir/"
done < files.txt
```